# Background Worker or Worker with Service Bus for SQL Database access?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm building a game for Windows Phone 8 and would like to use Windows Azure SQL Database for storing my users' data (mostly scores and rankings).

I have been reading Azure's documentation on SQL Database and found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336239.aspx) which describes just the scenario I'm looking for (it's Scenario B in the picture): I want my clients (the game running in a user's windows phone) to get data from an SQL Server through a middle application also hosted on Windows Azure.

By reading further the documentation (personally I think it's really messy and hard to find what you're looking for in there), I've learned that I could use Cloud Services for this middle application, however I'm not sure if I should use a background worker which provides an HTTP API or a worker with a Service Bus Relay (I discovered that I can use service bus in WP8 in [this link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed/)).

I've got a few questions that I couldn't find an answer to:

1) What would be the "standard" way to go in this case?

2) If both ways are acceptable, are there other advantages to using a Service Bus other than an easier way to connect and send messages to my middle application? What are the disadvantages?

3) Is a cloud service really what I'm looking for (and not just a VM with the middle application code running in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to answer these sort of question as there are lots of considerations. I don't believe there is a necessarily 'standard way'.

The Service Bus' relay service's purpose is to help traverse firewalls and NATs, not something that directly relates to your scenario, I suspect.

The Service Bus, though, also includes a messaging capability which provides queues, topics and subscriptions to use to exchange messages between clients or client/server.
You could use the phone client to write and read messages to/from queues. you would then have a worker role hosting your application logic and accessing the database as needed.

Some of the advantages of using messaging include being load leveller, helping handling peaks in traffic (at the expense of latency),  helping separating concerns and allowing you to accept requests from the clients when the backend is down as so can help with resiliency. 
In theory they can also help you deliver messages to the client in the same fashion, by using a queue or subscription per client, but for a large number of clients this may become a management issue.

On the downside you would have to work with what is a proprietary protocol, and will need to understand the characteristics and limitations of the service bus. you will need to manage the queues and topics over time. there will also be some increased latency, although typically not an issue and, finally, you will have to implement asynchronous messaging on the client side which has advantages but is also harder to implement.

I would imagine that many architectures follow the WEB API route by using a web role cloud service exposing the API. The web role can then perform any business logic and connect to the database in the background.

A third option, which you didn't mention, is to use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started/) and implement your business logic as a service API there

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have looked at the Mobile Services and I don't think it's what I need. From the tutorials and samples, it seems that the end user is allowed to interact directly with the database (as long as he has the app key which is distributed with the mobile app). This seems insecure as I need to "authenticate" in a certain way that the score being inserted in the database is indeed valid, and not just some fake score to get to the top position.
I think I'll take a look at the web API route. Is the WCF Service role used for these things?

Comment: Mobile services does not mean interacting with the database directly, you're calling a web api which may require (oAuth) authentication. outside mobile services - you could either choose the WCF route, or, probably better - ASP.net MVC Web API project deployed as an azure website or CloudService

Comment: Just checked ASP.Net MVC Web API - the description was misleading as it referred to "user interface" and I thought it would be similar to an ASP.NET Web Role, which just wasn't exactly what I wanted. The controllers in the MVC Web API with get and post functions are very familiar to me and seem like exactly what I need. Thank you for your help!